# How to make a Settings View Controller on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, settings

I am trying to put together a Settings View Controller. However, I'm not able to do static cells, even though the parent class is UITableViewController. My desired output looks like Facebook Messenger's (but with out the bottom tabs).

[image: Desired Settings View Controller]

1. im not able to use the static cells in says they can only be used imbedded in UITableViewController instance i have made the parent class a UITableViewController this is what i have so far

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to add some more detail regarding the cells you are creating and how they are failing - "not able to do" leaves an awful lot to guess.

Comment: What have you tried?  If your content is static you could just use a standard view and lay it out like a table, or if you want to use a tableview then you need to provide your static content via a tableviewDataSource

Comment: Can you elaborate on what requirement or feature is preventing you from using a static table view? I'm asking as this requirement will likely be relevant to an alternative approach as well.

Comment: have you set the delegate and datasource in the xib file ?

Comment: can you show us your code? it will help to fix issue easily

Comment: there is no code at the moment i just put it in and when i changed to static cells it gave me an error and i was wondering the solution